# Magento 2 Extra fees add with tax

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How can I apply tax in extra fee in magento 2? (With inc and Ex tax)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: did you manage it?

Answer (score -2):

Please try with below code, i hope its work for you.

Step1 : create sales.xml in you module etc folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
    <section name="quote">
        <group name="totals">

            <item name="fee" instance="Adamsmage\Checkoutfee\Model\Total\Fee" sort_order="150"/>

        </group>  
    </section>
</config>
```

step2 : `app\code\Adamsmage\Checkoutfee\view\frontend\web\js\view\checkout\cart\totals\fee.js`

```
define(
    [
        'Adamsmage_Checkoutfee/js/view/checkout/summary/fee'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({

            /**
             * @override
             */
            isDisplayed: function () {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

step3: `app\code\Adamsmage\Checkoutfee\view\frontend\web\js\view\checkout\summary\fee.js`

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
    ],
    function (Component, quote, priceUtils, totals) {
        "use strict";
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed: window.checkoutConfig.isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed || false,
                template: 'Adamsmage_Checkoutfee/checkout/summary/fee'
            },
            totals: quote.getTotals(),
            isTaxDisplayedInGrandTotal: window.checkoutConfig.includeTaxInGrandTotal || false,
            isDisplayed: function() {
                return this.isFullMode();
            },
            getValue: function() {
                var price = 0;
                if (this.totals()) {
                    price = totals.getSegment('fee').value;
                }
                return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
            },
            getBaseValue: function() {
                var price = 0;
                if (this.totals()) {
                    price = this.totals().base_fee;
                }
                return priceUtils.formatPrice(price, quote.getBasePriceFormat());
            }
        });
    }
);
```

step4 :  `app\code\Adamsmage\Checkoutfee\view\frontend\web\template\checkout\summary\fee.html`

```
 <tr class="totals fee excl">
            <th class="mark" scope="row">
                <span class="label" data-bind="text: title"></span>
                <span class="value" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span>
            </th>
            <td class="amount">

                <span class="price"
                      data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': title}"></span>


            </td>
        </tr>
```

step5 : `app\code\Adamsmage\Checkoutfee\view\frontend\web\template\checkout\cart\totals\fee.html`

```
<tr class="totals fee excl">
    <th class="mark" colspan="1" scope="row" data-bind="text: title"></th>
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

step6 : `app\code\Adamsmage\Checkoutfee\Model\Total\Fee.php`

```
namespace Adamsmage\Checkoutfee\Model\Total;


class Fee extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal
{

    protected $quoteValidator = null; 

    public function __construct(\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteValidator $quoteValidator)
    {
        $this->quoteValidator = $quoteValidator;
    }
  public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ) {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);


        $exist_amount = 0; //$quote->getFee(); 
        $fee = 100; //Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::getFee();
        $balance = $fee - $exist_amount;

        $total->setTotalAmount('fee', $balance);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('fee', $balance);

        $total->setFee($balance);
        $total->setBaseFee($balance);

        $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal() + $balance);
        $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() + $balance);


        return $this;
    } 

    protected function clearValues(Address\Total $total)
    {
        $total->setTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('tax', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('tax', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setSubtotalInclTax(0);
        $total->setBaseSubtotalInclTax(0);
    }
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param Address\Total $total
     * @return array|null
     */
    /**
     * Assign subtotal amount and label to address object
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param Address\Total $total
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total)
    {
        return [
            'code' => 'fee',
            'title' => 'Extra Fee',
            'value' => 100
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get Subtotal label
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getLabel()
    {
        return __('Extra Fee');
    }
}
```

step7 :`app\code\Adamsmage\Checkoutfee\etc\module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Adamsmage_Checkoutfee" setup_version="2.0.6" schema_version="2.0.6">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

step8 : `app\code\Adamsmage\Checkoutfee\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">


                                <item name="fee" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Adamsmage_Checkoutfee/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/fee</item>
                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                         <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Adamsmage_Checkoutfee/checkout/cart/totals/fee</item>
                                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Extra Fee</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>

                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

step9 : `app\code\Adamsmage\Checkoutfee\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">

                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                       <item name="fee" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Adamsmage_Checkoutfee/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/fee</item>
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                 <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Adamsmage_Checkoutfee/checkout/cart/totals/fee</item>
                                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Extra Fee</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="details" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/item/details/subtotal</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

step10 : `app\code\Adamsmage\Checkoutfee\view\frontend\layout\sales_order_view.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>        
        <referenceContainer name="order_totals">
            <block class="Adamsmage\Checkoutfee\Block\Sales\Order\Fee" name="fee"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

step11 : `app\code\Adamsmage\Checkoutfee\Block\Sales\Order\Fee.php`

```
namespace Adamsmage\Checkoutfee\Block\Sales\Order;



    class Fee extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {
        /**
         * Tax configuration model
         *
         * @var \Magento\Tax\Model\Config
         */
        protected $_config;

        /**
         * @var Order
         */
        protected $_order;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\DataObject
         */
        protected $_source;

        /**
         * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
         * @param \Magento\Tax\Model\Config $taxConfig
         * @param array $data
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Tax\Model\Config $taxConfig,
            array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->_config = $taxConfig;
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }

        /**
         * Check if we nedd display full tax total info
         *
         * @return bool
         */
        public function displayFullSummary()
        {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Get data (totals) source model
         *
         * @return \Magento\Framework\DataObject
         */
        public function getSource()
        {
            return $this->_source;
        } 
        public function getStore()
        {
            return $this->_order->getStore();
        }

          /**
         * @return Order
         */
        public function getOrder()
        {
            return $this->_order;
        }

        /**
         * @return array
         */
        public function getLabelProperties()
        {
            return $this->getParentBlock()->getLabelProperties();
        }

        /**
         * @return array
         */
        public function getValueProperties()
        {
            return $this->getParentBlock()->getValueProperties();
        }

        /**
         * Initialize all order totals relates with tax
         *
         * @return \Magento\Tax\Block\Sales\Order\Tax
         */
         public function initTotals()
        {

            $parent = $this->getParentBlock();
            $this->_order = $parent->getOrder();
            $this->_source = $parent->getSource();

            $store = $this->getStore();

            $fee = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                    [
                        'code' => 'fee',
                        'strong' => false,
                        'value' => 50,
                        //'value' => $this->_source->getFee(),
                        'label' => __('Extra Fee'),
                    ]
                );

                $parent->addTotal($fee, 'fee');
               // $this->_addTax('grand_total');
                $parent->addTotal($fee, 'fee');


                return $this;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I have already tried this code. It only adds extra fee not calculate tax.

Comment: I was done with my side with some customization Model\Total\Fee.php with this file.

Comment: In you code you are just add the fee not calculate tax.